# Installing APEX 19.2

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I installed APEX 19.2 with ORDS on tomcat. Previously i had a 19.1 version installed. I tried to uprgrade and remove and install from beggining. But still i get an error

> There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files are not up-to-date! The files for version 19.1.0.00.15 have been loaded, but 19.2.0.00.18 is expected. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide.

I can't find the source of this error.

Also, how to configure the image source? I find that even if I delete the /i/ folder from webapps ORACLE APEX still works.

I figure out there is a weird problem. I unziped APEX to C:\apex, then when i run cmd from this folder and try @apex_epg_config.sql with value C: i get and info that

```
SQL> @apex_epg_config.sql C:
```

> Loading images directory: C:/apex/images

And that seems to be right but then i get an error ORA-22288

> No such file or directory

EDIT: i worked with @apex_epg_config.sql but still there is a error with version of files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
ehh that's really silly

To solve the problem ORA-22288 I copied the image files from my local directory to the directory on the same server where db is running. The second thing is to make sure that Oracle or another user can read from your folder (e.g. / Home / username)

Then just run

```
@apex_epg_config.sql /home/username
```

After all, simply clear the cache of cookies and data from your web browser. This last point was so obvious, but at first I didn't think about it.

Comment: Is it required to run apex_epg_config.sql?  For me just copying the images to i folder worked.

Answer (score 0):

I run ORDS under Tomcat. In my installation, at the same level where the ords.war file resides ($CATALINA_HOME/webapps), there is a directory called "i", which is referenced as the images directory. Make sure you have the images directory from the APEX version you're installing copied to that directory.

Here's a way to find  out how the image URL is configured. Make sure that the "apex_190200" is the correct schema in the example below

```
set serveroutput on
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(apex_190200.wwv_flow_image_prefix.g_image_prefix);
end;
/
```

/i/

[Reference](http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2019/03/where-are-my-static-application-files.html)

Comment: I have, even when i run {host}:port/i/apex_version.txt i get "Application Express Version:  19.2"

Comment: Maybe i have something wrong (but i dont know what) with config. Even if i delete this /i/ folder oracle apex still working after tomcat restart

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Maybe drop all of the APEX related schemas and start from scratch? There's an apxremov.sql script that you can run.

Comment: I used that script and I removed manually all users with '%APEX%' and '%ORDS%' and FLOW_FILES and still no :( I have the problem with @apex_epg_config.sql